# iPhone - save UIImageView state

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have created a subclass of UIImageView and I am handling the touches for its objects inside the subclass itself.

Now when the user is about to exit the app I want to save the state of the images. And as there are multiple transforms which might have taken place on the images (I am saving all the transforms in an array), I want to be able to save these objects in applicationWillTerminate.

Is there any way I can save these objects? Or do I have to save everything individually? If I do, how do I save all the transformations which have happened on the image view objects till the user exits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView` conforms to `NSCoding`. You will need to implement `encodeWithCoder:` in your `UIImageView` subclass to allow it to be serialised. You use the passed encoder to serialise the important member variables, in this case your images then call the superclass' `encodeWithCoder:`.

You do the the inverse of this in `initWithCoder:` an you've got your original state back.

If your images are instances of `UIImage` you'll have a bit more work to do since it doesn't conform to `NSCoding`. You might be able to get away with converting the image data to an `NSData` object and encoding that depending on your requirements. Here's an example of how this can be done: http://www.nixwire.com/getting-uiimage-to-work-with-nscoding-encodewithcoder/

Have a look at the Archives and Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am facing another issue. encodeWithCoder is giving an exception in my UIImageView subclass. It throws and error [UIImage encodeWithCoder:] invalid method. But I am not invoking encodeWithCoder on a UIImage object, only on UIImageView and NSMutableDictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: turns out the other link you had mentioned (nixwire) mentions exactly the issue I am facing :) Thanks again

Comment: I have the same problem,Is there any tutorial/sample application available for this where i can find some reference?