# save UIImageView state & the save the Entire View

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPad app where you add photos to a page. I then want to save the photos positions, then add further pages with more photo positions and  eventually save all the pagesto be looked at later in a slideshow style.

Can anyone advise 
1. Saving UIImageView states when moving to new views (or swapping views)
  - I see this on using NSCoding  [iPhone - save UIImageView state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985326/iphone-save-uiimageview-state)  - but am at a lose - any more examples ?
2. How to save the 'entire' set of view to look at later (like a slideshow)
  - no idea on where to start with this ? array ? coredata ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to seems pretty relevant here.  I think the topic you need to understand is serialization and deserialization.  Serialization, briefly, is the act of transforming a data structure or object into another format (such as XML/JSON/binary) that can be then turned back into a data structure or object through deserialization.  The answer you linked to discusses how Cocoa suggests a developer handle this serialization/deserialization lifecycle.

So you should come up with what you need to save from your view(s).  Once you have that you can write serializers and deserializers to save/reload that information.  And once you've reloaded the information it should be straight forward to update the current view with the loaded information.

Comment: oh boy - thanks I did start reading that documentation and go so confused ! :D