# Storing UIImageViews and their locations in the superview

Tags: iphone

How are UIImageViews stored/serialized so that they can be loaded upon app relaunch?

Also I would like to store their current position in the superview along with each image. How is this detected?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did it by creating a separate class (I call it an image view manager) to hold the image view properties such as position, image name, etc. and then subclassed UIImageView to have a reference to a instance of the image view manager and update its properties when something in the image view changes, such as location. Then you just have to serialize the image managers and when you restart recreate the image views from the information in each manager (though I used core data since this was part of a larger core data application).

**Manager Class:**

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface ImageViewManager :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * imageLastY;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * imageZorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * imageLastX;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageName;

@end
```

**UIImageViewClass:**

---- Interface -----

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ImageViewManager.h"

@protocol MyImageViewDelegate
-(void)didUpdateImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView;
@end

@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {

    ImageViewManager *imageViewManager;
    id <MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;

}   
@property (nonatomic, retain) ImageViewManager *imageViewManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image andImageViewManager:(ImageViewManager *)ivm;
@end
```

--- Implementation ---------

```
#import "MyImageView.h"


@implementation MyImageView
@synthesize imageViewManager;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image andImageViewManager:(ImageViewManager *)ivm {

    if (self = [super initWithImage:image]) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.imageViewManager = ivm;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    CGPoint prevlocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.superview];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    location.x = (self.center.x - (prevlocation.x - location.x));
    location.y = (self.center.y - (prevlocation.y - location.y));
    self.center = location;
    self.imageViewManager.imageLastX = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.center.x];
    self.imageViewManager.imageLastY = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.center.y];

    }

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.delegate didUpdateImageView:self];
}   

- (void)dealloc {
    [imageViewManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may better answer your question than my original answer: [iPhone - save UIImageView state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985326/iphone-save-uiimageview-state)